# Facebook SDK doesn't fire in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using as title says I am doing a facebook login with javascript SDK.
It works well in all browsers except certain versions of IE.

It doesn't work on my local IE11 and on IE7 on browserstack.com(but does work on their IE11).

Here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  </script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'INSERT SOME APP ID',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
    status     : true,                    // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert('authorized');
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    alert('logged in but not authorized');
    } else {
    alert('logged off');
    }
  });

 };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's pretty much sample from their documentation.
fbAsyncInit just doesn't get called no matter what I do.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that sdk.js is loading **after** `window.fbAsyncInit` has been defined? I'd move the definition of `window.fbAsyncInit` so that it occurs **above** the line `//load the SDK asynchronously`

Comment: @spender Yes I tried that but doesnt work. Now I tried **synchronous** loading(loading sdk after fbAsync) that solves problem in my local IE11 but not on IE7 on browserstack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening your html as a file on your local machine?

I've had this problem before. the culprit is the protocol relative url

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

If you are calling it from file:///home/me/mycoolwebpage.html then the script will not load as it uses the same protocol and looks for `file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` which does not exist.

While it is on your local machine, use the full `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` and then switch that out for `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` when you upload it.

Comment: Nope, I uploaded it to server. Interesting thing is request to sdk.js is not there when i check network requests.